# Why is the argument passed in to my recursive function not updating its value?

Tags: javascript, recursion

I'm just playing around with simple recursion and functions. Nothing too serious, but not doing what I expect:

```
    var recursive = function adder (x) {
  x = ++x
  if (x < 10) {
    console.log('x is now: ' + x)
    adder(x)
  }
  return x
}

console.log(recursive(5))
```

This completes the loop and runs properly, but am wondering why the 'final' output is '6.' Why don't I get the 'final' value of x after all the recursion is done?

Comment: I edited it. No longer hung up on 'x++; thanks to below answer.

Comment: it's an interesting question, and it has to do with not returning the result of the recursive call of `adder`. as i wrote before, you need to assign the return value of `adder` to `x`. but easy closing prevents from answering.

Comment: Yes @NinaScholz By putting x = adder(x) in that 'if' loop, I get back 10, as expected. :)
However, the return x MUST be outside of 'if' loop, which I thought was a bit strange...:| It returns 'undefined' otherwise...

Comment: @Nina Scholz: he completely edited the question, which makes my answer below unneccessary...

Comment: @VisWebsoft: the highest function in the stack has x=10, therefore it wont go trough the if, and will return undefined ( wich then cycles up to the console.log), so the return needs to be outside the loop...

Comment: @Jonasw Yeah, I was wondering if I shouldn't have just started a new question. Wasn't sure, and open to suggestions on how to handle an 'evolving question' scenario. I DID mark your answer as helpful, because it did get me past the initial stumbling block, but, no it's not the actual complete answer.

Comment: @Jonasw With your last comment, I believe I have a 'full' understanding of what's happening here. If you want to make that as your answer, I'll gladly 'accept' it. Thanks!

Comment: Youre welcome ;) however, please simply open a new question next time as editing/ extending questions creates chaos...

Comment: @Jonasw Will do.

Answer (score 3):

```
x=++x;
x+=1;
x++;
++x;
```

You need either the *pre increment* or the *increase by* operator, or the postincrement without an reassignment. The post increment retuns first, then increments...

```
alert((1)++)//1
```

Some ongoing explanations:

```
var recursive = function adder (x) {
  ++x;
  if (x < 10) {
   console.log('x is now: ' + x)
   return adder(x); //lets return our added result
  }
 return x;//if x=10 lets return 10
}

console.log(recursive(5))//will log 10
```

It mainly didnt work as expected as primitives are passed by value. So there are actually 5 different x variables in 5 different contexts of adder...

Unlike primitives, objects are passed by reference:

```
function adder(obj){
 obj.x++;
 if(obj.x<10){
   adder(obj);
 }
}

var test={x:1};
adder(test);
console.log(test.x);
```

Comment: please remove the assignment of a not necessary value to the same variable. just replace `x = ++x;` with more concise and not misleading `++x;`.